# How to show metallic texture in scene kit

Tags: xcode, scenekit

I'm an ultra-noob in sceneKit and I have a problem with the appearance of (metallic texture) in SceneKit, I used this code to show it.

```
 let glassesFrame = contentNode!.childNode(withName: "Metallic_Part",
                                                            recursively: true)

        glassesFrame?.geometry?.firstMaterial?.lightingModel = .physicallyBased
         glassesFrame?.geometry?.firstMaterial?.metalness.contents = 0.8
         glassesFrame?.geometry?.firstMaterial?.roughness.contents = 0.2
```

but the problem is that the values of (**metalness, roughness**) affects the Darkening of color (the **greater** the value of the metal, the **darker** the color).

Here is an example for more clarification:

metalness:**0.2**   roughness: **0.8** : [here is the result](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vrWjctO7Z6Nrc7wliDgFu-X522SDoKCV/view?usp=sharing)

metalness:**0.8**   roughness: **0.2** : [here is the result](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ldPf5twnSv3pNPxJ6l8dnXUoTUcpicZX/view?usp=sharing)

and when I set "1" as a value for the metalness the color changed to black, [here is the result](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sGwP3qhZMzselRUAvhAKWdYIBRu8NteS/view?usp=sharing)

and here is the model I used: Model in Sketchfab : https://skfb.ly/6QVTQ

**How can I make the metal look natural (mirror like).**
here is the full code:

```
class BlendShapeCharacter: NSObject, VirtualContentController {

    var contentNode: SCNNode?

    private var originalJawY: Float = 0

    private lazy var jawNode = contentNode!


    private lazy var jawHeight: Float = {
        let (min, max) = jawNode.boundingBox
        return max.y - min.y
    }()

    func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, nodeFor anchor: ARAnchor) -> SCNNode? {
        guard anchor is ARFaceAnchor else { return nil }

        contentNode = SCNReferenceNode(named: "Glasses")
        let glassesFrame = contentNode!.childNode(withName: "Metallic_Part",
                                                            recursively: true)

        glassesFrame?.geometry?.firstMaterial?.lightingModel = .physicallyBased
         glassesFrame?.geometry?.firstMaterial?.metalness.contents = 0.8
         glassesFrame?.geometry?.firstMaterial?.roughness.contents = 0.2


        let lens1 = contentNode!.childNode(withName: "Glass_Part",
                                                     recursively: true)

        let material = SCNMaterial()
        material.lightingModel = .phong
        material.diffuse.contents = UIColor(white: 0.2,
                                            alpha: 1)
        material.diffuse.intensity = 0.9
        material.specular.contents = UIColor(white: 1,
                                             alpha: 1)
        material.specular.intensity = 1.0
        material.reflective.contents = UIImage(named:"Models.scnassets/texture.png")
        material.reflective.intensity = 2.0
        material.transparencyMode = .dualLayer
        material.fresnelExponent = 2.2
        material.isDoubleSided = true
        material.blendMode = .alpha
        material.shininess = 100
        material.transparency.native = 0.4
        material.cullMode = .back

        lens1?.geometry?.firstMaterial = material

        originalJawY = jawNode.position.y
        return contentNode
    }
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Has the value of [`environmentTexturing`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arworldtrackingconfiguration/2977509-environmenttexturing) been set to `AREnvironmentTexturingManual` or `AREnvironmentTexturingAutomatic`?

> In 3D asset rendering, environment textures are the basis for
>   image-based lighting algorithms where surfaces can realistically
>   reflect light from their surroundings. ARKit can generate environment
>   textures during an AR session using camera imagery, allowing SceneKit
>   or a custom rendering engine to provide realistic image-based lighting
>   for virtual objects in your AR experience.

Comment: Actually I don't have "environmentTexturing" in my code at all. can you tell me how and where should I add it to my code

Comment: Oh man I would love to have some kind of substitute for this in SceneKit. Is there such a thing? I don’t wanna require camera access and/or dwelve into ARKit for now for my project

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the scenes [lightingEnvironment](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnscene/1639532-lightingenvironment) properties.  If you want the reflection to look like the surrounding area you can also use an image for the scenes background contents to provide more realism.  [Great example found here.](https://github.com/asavihay/PBROrbs-iOS10-SceneKit)

```
let backgroundImage = UIImage(named: "ImageName")
scene.background.contents = backgroundImage

let environmentImage = UIImage(named: "ImageName")
scene.lightingEnvironment.contents = environmentImage
scene.lightingEnvironment.intensity = 2
```